# Хочу связать базу данных SQL и Pyqt. Хочу добавить элементы 1 столбца в QCombobox и чтобы выводились остальные данные этого элемента

Tags: python-3.x, sql, pyqt5, sqlite3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в QComboBox нужно вместить все элементы столбца Action и чтобы выводились остальные столбцы выбранного элемента

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: мне нужно вывести элементы столбца Action в QCombobox и вывести элементы остальных столбцов в QTableWidget

Comment: допустим элемент это shoot, значит нужно в QTableWidjet вывести остальные данные из остальных столбцов